# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array

Tags: c#, base64

I'm getting a "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array." inside of the IF(){...} are variations i have tried to get it to work. it fails in the first line without calling decrypt(...) proving it's not that functions problem. i get the same error inside with the first decrypt(...) call. the last one using the encoding.ascii... will get me inside the function, but then it fails inside the function. I'm getting the proper encrypted info from the database to string SSnum. it's value is: 4+mFeTp3tPF

```
try
{
    string SSnum = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Social Security"));
    if (isEncrypted)
    {
      byte[] temp = Convert.FromBase64String(SSnum);
      //SSnum = decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(SSnum), Key, IV);
      //SSnum = decrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SSnum), Key, IV);
    }
    txt_Social_Security.Text = SSnum;
}
catch { txt_Social_Security.Text = ""; }
```

I've been told to use the Convert.FromBase64String() and not the ASCII method...so why is it failing, how can i fix it?

Comment: please don't put things like "c#" in the title. That's what tags are for.

Comment: 4+mFeTp3tPF does not look like a valid base64 value. It contains 11 chars, while base64 value lengths should be multiples of 4. With padding, it should look like 4+mFeTp3tPF= (where = is used for padding). You should check how the base64 value gets generated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> it's value is: 4+mFeTp3tPF

You are receiving this error because that value, `4+mFeTp3tPF`, is in fact **not** valid Base64.

Is it possible you are simply missing the required padding character, as so `4+mFeTp3tPF=`?

Comment: that would make sense, in the sql database it's a varchar(11), so any '=' would get truncated... and that also explains why i have seen so many equal signs sometimes! i saw somewhere that it's multiples of 4? so make my varchar(11) to varchar(12)..or more will be the fix, right?

Comment: Yes, if your DB is truncating, you need to make the field longer.  No point skimping on length, either.  If it is varchar, there is no difference in size between varchar(12) and varchar(255) (and on MSSQL, all the way up to varchar(4000).  This is because the field contains an integer specifying the length of the text, rather than blocking off 11 or 12 or 4000 characters.  See wikipedia for Base64 specification: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Answer (score 24):

Base64 data length should be multiple of 4 and with padding char '='
You can change your data as valid base64 data.

```
string dummyData = imgData.Trim().Replace(" ", "+");
if (dummyData.Length % 4 > 0)
dummyData = dummyData.PadRight(dummyData.Length + 4 - dummyData.Length % 4, '=');
byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(dummyData);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9301545/2024022

This will help you , try once. 
Thanks
suribabu.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that you have a Base64 string? Base64 is a means of encoding binary data into a string while only using standard 7-bit ASCII characters. It's *not* a string encoding like ASCII and has some control bytes present. You have a Base64 string if you're using `Convert.ToBase64String` to obtain the value (which, if you're trying to store binary data as a string, is your best bet)

Judging by your error (and your example data), I'm assuming that you do *not* have a Base64 string. If you need to store binary data in the database, you can either create a column using a binary type or encode the string into Base64 by using `Convert.ToBase64String`.

```
byte[] inputData = ...;

string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(inputData);

byte[] outputData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
```

Here, `outputData` should contain the same data as `inputData`.

If what you have is just an ASCII-encoded string, then your original practice of using `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()` is correct, but you should change this to use a Base64 string if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that string **4+mFeTp3tPF** is  well-formed Base64 string? 
I've tried some online services - no one could convert it.

Comment: One equal sing is senseless - try http://base64.ru/ or http://home1.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/ or http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/Base64Decode/. I suppose some error has occured during submitting data to database.

Answer (score -1):

replace

> byte[] temp = Convert.FromBase64String(SSnum);

to this

> var temp = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SSnum);