# ViewState Chunking in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, page-lifecycle

I keep on hearing this words "Viewstate Chunking".
What is Viewstate Chunking?

And how it is working for ASP.NET pages?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When the ViewState in your page becomes very large it can be a problem since some firewalls and proxies will prevent access to pages containing huge ViewState sizes. For this purpose ASP.NET introduces the ViewState Chunking mechanism. So ASP.NET enables splitting of the ViewState's single hidden field into several using the MaxPageStateFieldLength property in the web.config  section.

When the MaxPageStateFieldLength property is set to a positive number, the view state sent to the client browser is broken into multiple hidden fields.

Setting the MaxPageStateFieldLength property to a negative number (the default) indicates that the view-state field should not be separated into chunks. Setting the MaxPageStateFieldLength to a small number may result in poor performance.

Sample ViewState before:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE"value="/wEPDwUKLTk2Njk3OTQxNg9kFgICAw9kFgICCQ88KwANAGQYAQUJR3Jp
ZFZpZXcxD2dk4sjERFfnDXV/hMFGAL10HQUnZbk=" />
```

Then set in web.config:

```
<pages maxPageStateFieldLength="40">
```

Sample ViewState After :

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEFIELDCOUNT" id="__VIEWSTATEFIELDCOUNT"value="3" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE"
id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTk2Njk3OTQxNg9kFgICAw9kFgICCQ88" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE1"
id="__VIEWSTATE1" value="KwANAGQYAQUJR3JpZFZpZXcxD2dk4sjERFfnDXV/" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE2"
id="__VIEWSTATE2" value="hMFGAL10HQUnZbk=" />
```

hope it help you!

Comment: The EVENTVALIDATION hidden field can also become large. It is possible to chunk this also?

Comment: please note that the <pages> element sits inside the <system.web> element in web.config.

Answer (score 4):

From [What's New in ASP.NET State Management - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178577%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> If the amount of view-state data becomes too large, view-state
>   chunking will automatically split the data into chunks and put the
>   data into multiple hidden-form fields.

**Why do we need Viewstate Chunking?**

Here is an exerpt from [ViewState Overivew - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178198%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Another important consideration is that if the amount of data in a
>   hidden field becomes large, some proxies and firewalls will prevent
>   access to the page that contains them. Because the maximum amount can
>   vary with different firewall and proxy implementations, large hidden
>   fields can cause sporadic problems. To help avoid this problem, if the
>   amount of data stored in the ViewState property exceeds the value
>   specified in the page's [MaxPageStateFieldLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maxpagestatefieldlength%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property, the page
>   splits view state into multiple hidden fields to reduce the size of
>   each individual field below the size that firewalls reject.