# How to disable viewstate size limit in ASP.NET webconfig

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-config

For now on I've been investigating this error:

> The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

I've come out with this: [One possible reason for “The state information is invalid for this page…” exception](http://blog.syedgakbar.com/2007/11/08/one-possible-reason-for-the-state-information-is-invalid-for-this-page-exception/)

This guy just found exactly the same issue I'm fighting for. Because in the majority of my pages there are hidden fields that are changing constantly the size of the viewstate and the exception throws randomly. But i've just don't understand how to do this:

> For now I have just disabled the ViewState size limit in the client website and things seems back to normal.

**How did he disabled the size limit of the view state?** If I could disable it I could avoid the problem. But he didn't post the code changed in his web.config.
And I'm bit lost here. Any help whould be appreciated.

This is what I have on my web.config

```
<httpRuntime useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" requestLengthDiskThreshold="15360" targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="118192" executionTimeout="3600" />
<pages buffer="true" enableSessionState="true" enableViewState="true" validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
```

Disabling the entire viewstate is not a solution.

**If is not posible to acomplish the disabling of view state size limit, where and when in my global.asax should I make the store/load of viewstate through session ?**

Comment: you can always do viewstate chunking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413986/viewstate-chunking-in-asp-net

Comment: Hi @ngeksyo Thanks for your answer i'll try also what you mention.