# "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string" when decoding JWT.IO token

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a JWT token, and I'm trying to decode the payload.  The string I'm trying to decode is:

`eyJzdWIiOiIyMzEzOTE6MTAxMjpFQiBBZG1pbixFQiBDaGVjayBJbi9PdXQgUmVzb3VyY2VzLEVCIE1hc3RlciBBZG1pbiIsImV4cCI6IjE1NDUyNTc2MDkiLCJhdWQiOiI0OTk0QzgxMC02QUMyLTQ3NkYtQjUyQi04MjQ5NUUzRUNBNTgifQ`

If I go to https://www.base64decode.org/ and plug in that string, it decodes just fine to:

```
{"sub":"231391:1012:EB Admin,EB Check In/Out Resources,EB Master Admin","exp":"1545257466","aud":"4994C810-6AC2-476F-B52B-82495E3ECA58"}
```

But with this:

```
byte[] dataPayload = Convert.FromBase64String(tokenPayload);
```

I get:

> Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT:**

This is the entire JWT, as delivered by JWT.IO (i added line breaks so it's easier to read)...

eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.
eyJzdWIiOiIyMzEzOTE6MTAxMjpFQiBBZG1pbixFQiBDaGVjayBJbi9PdXQgUmVzb3VyY2VzLEVCIE1hc3RlciBBZG1pbiIsImV4cCI6IjE1NDUyNTc4ODMiLCJhdWQiOiI0OTk0QzgxMC02QUMyLTQ3NkYtQjUyQi04MjQ5NUUzRUNBNTgifQ.
0oaXmDOlYdHSTLo7t7fFpHG2T0DMRpAoERxiM_Ur5O4

This same two line of code have been working fine:

```
string tokenPayload = _jwtData.WebToken.Split('.')[1];
byte[] dataPayload = Convert.FromBase64String(tokenPayload);
```

But for some reason that I don't understand, now I am getting this error.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858761/what-causing-this-invalid-length-for-a-base-64-char-array/9301545#9301545

Comment: Hint: count the characters in your base64-encoded string. Some libraries are more forgiving than others.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing padding. Take a look at the following: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding

So in your case, the correct JWT token is: eyJzdWIiOiIyMzEzOTE6MTAxMjpFQiBBZG1pbixFQiBDaGVjayBJbi9PdXQgUmVzb3VyY2VzLEVCIE1hc3RlciBBZG1pbiIsImV4cCI6IjE1NDUyNTc2MDkiLCJhdWQiOiI0OTk0QzgxMC02QUMyLTQ3NkYtQjUyQi04MjQ5NUUzRUNBNTgifQ==

Comment: Ok? what's odd is that this same line of code has worked before. It just all of a sudden stopped working.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston The string must have been different in the past.

Comment: see edit to the OP

Comment: Test the string's length before you try to decode it.  If it's off, add some padding.  Whoever is building the JWT isn't doing the padding properly, it seems

Answer (score 1):

Seems JWT.IO has their own method of decoding their own payload. This is the right way to do it:

```
string jwt = JWT.Decode("...token...", "...encoded Secret Key...", JwsAlgorithm.HS256);
```

Where JWT is `Jose.JWT` from their NuGet package.